# How can I only pass in Partition Key when using ReadItemAsync? - Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to run `ReadItemAsync` against a Partition Key only. The Key is a 7 digit number that users will search for. The Partition Key exists in the same container but multiple times as we've split the data up based on month, therefore, each Partition Key will exist 12 times but the ID will change.

code is literally:
`var feedIterator = await Container.ReadItemAsync<JObject>("id", new PartitionKey(partitionKey));`

DB Schema:

| id | /partitionKey |
| --- | --- |
| abcd1234-1111-2222-9f4a-8fea7044faf4 | 1200001 |
| abcd1234-1111-2222-9d1e-49096cc32731 | 1200001 |
| abcd1234-1111-2222-a6ab-f249eed57eb7 | 1200001 |
| abcd1234-1111-2222-ba31-422ccccd1aef | 1200001 |
| abcd1234-1111-2222-ba14-d6fb786dab3e | 1200001 |
| abcd1234-1111-2222-89a0-c5434c3192d0 | 1200001 |
| abcd1234-1111-2222-b8fb-9d5fdd0ab811 | 1200001 |

Cheers,
Sam

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit? Read Item is an operation to read 1 document. Is your intent reading all the documents in a Partition Key? Or are you asking how to call ReadItemAsync to read those individual documents?

Comment: You can't call `ReadItemAsync()` to return more than one item - its sole design is to fetch a single item, in its entirety, based on id + partition key value. For multiple document retrieval, you have to execute a query (which then lets you choose any subset of properties to return, as well)

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta it is to read multiple documents with the same partitionKey. I am trying to optimise performance.

Comment: @SCramphorn - please try writing a query, instead of a read. Then, if you run into a specific issue, you can post a question related to that. As I already stated... you simply cannot return more than one document with the *read* operation (which maps to a single underlying REST API call), and need to write a query.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the Ids and Partition Key Values of the documents you want to read, you can use `container.ReadManyItemsAsync`:

```
List<(string, PartitionKey)> itemList = new List<(string, PartitionKey)>
{
  ("abcd1234-1111-2222-9f4a-8fea7044faf4", new PartitionKey("1200001")),
  ("abcd1234-1111-2222-9d1e-49096cc32731", new PartitionKey("1200001")),
  ("abcd1234-1111-2222-a6ab-f249eed57eb7", new PartitionKey("1200001")),
...
;

Console.WriteLine("\nItems in read list:" + itemList.Count);
FeedResponse<SalesOrder> feedResponse = await container.ReadManyItemsAsync<SalesOrder>(
```

Full example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/ItemManagement/Program.cs#L425

If you don't know the ids and just the Partition Key Value, then you can do a query:

```
using (FeedIterator<MyItem> feedIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<MyItem>(
    "SELECT * FROM c",
    requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions() { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("1200001")}))
{
    // ...
}
```

Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/performance-tips-query-sdk?tabs=v3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#use-single-partition-queries

Comment: Thanks, but I am finding a huge performance dip in this. I am running the second query, however it takes around 2 seconds in C#, whereas querying directly in Portal Azuzre, it takes 50ms...

Comment: You cannot compare the Azure Portal versus a C# application. The Azure Portal is a NodeJS app performing a REST API request from your browser. The C# application is using the C# client to perform TCP operations directly on the backend replica. If your concern is about performance on C#, please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-dotnet-sdk-slow-request?tabs=cpu-new, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3-sql. The scope of this question is from the API perspective, how to achieve certain operations, not latency.